# tqdm inside celery worker

Tags: python, flask, logging, celery, celery-task

I am using celery for async tasks in my flask app.
One of the celery tasks using an external package (sentence-transformers) that uses tqdm in its functionality. It is possible to enable/disable the tqdm bar.

my celery worker is carsh always in that line:

```py
for start_index in trange(0, len(sentences), batch_size, desc="Batches", disable=not show_progress_bar):
```

this is the error:

```
[2023-05-27 22:49:59,012: ERROR/MainProcess] Process 'ForkPoolWorker-4' pid:52707 exited with 'signal 5 (SIGTRAP)'
[2023-05-27 22:49:59,044: ERROR/MainProcess] Task handler raised error: WorkerLostError('Worker exited prematurely: signal 5 (SIGTRAP) Job: 0.')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "miniconda3/envs/base/lib/python3.8/site-packages/billiard/pool.py", line 1265, in mark_as_worker_lost
    raise WorkerLostError(
billiard.exceptions.WorkerLostError: Worker exited prematurely: signal 5 (SIGTRAP) Job: 0.
```

this is my logger setup:

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(name)s - %(message)s',
                    datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S', level=logging.INFO)
```

and this is how I starting the celery:

```
celery -A celery_setup.celery worker --loglevel=info  --concurrency=4
```

any ideas?

Comment: It turns out that adding `-P threads` flag in the celery command solved it.